# Pascal. Как вообще работать с переменными типа char?

Tags: pascal

Если в текст входят не только символы, соответствующие десятичным цифрам, выдать сообщение о том, что текст некорректен. Если текст можно интерпретировать как запись положительного десятичного числа, то определить -- является ли оно кратным 6 с помощью признака делимости. Также если значение такого числа допустимо для типа integer, вычислить это значение по схеме Горнера и определить -- является ли нулем остаток от его деления на нацело на 6.

Answer (score 0):

Что то я в вашем вопросе насчитал совсем не один вопрос :)
Отвечу на основной.

Я бы сделал так. В Pascal есть отличная функция StrToInt - преобразует строку (или массив Char, как у вас видимо) в число. Через try except можно отловить ошибку, если в строке не число. А дальше уже работаете с числом как вам надо. Умеет работать не только с десятичным представлением кстати.

Comment: "если значение такого числа допустимо для типа integer"